# How to create a class that has a single thread-safe static instance?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm new to working with multi-thread compatible software, so this may well be a really simple question.

If I have created a class in which I want to expose a static instance (of itself), is there a way to synchronize it across threads so that the current internal state of it is the same everywhere, and if so what would be the way to accomplish this?

The class (in my particular case) is similar to the built in Random Class, and I can't ensure that all calls will originate from the same thread, but no matter which thread needs to generate a value, I need to ensure that the state across threads remains the same.

As requested I will post the code relating to the state of the class as well as the static access members

```
public class ChaosEngine {
    // The internal state of the class that needs to be synchronized
    private int _Seed;
    private int _INext;
    private int _INextP;
    private int[] _SeedArray;
    public int Seed{ get=>_Seed; set=>Reseed(value); }
    // The shared instance (as it is currently written)
    [ThreadStatic] private static ChaosEngine _Shared;
    public static ChaosEngine Shared {
        get {
            if(_Shared == null)
                _Shared = new ChaosEngine();
            return _Shared;
        }
    }
}
```

If the full code is required it can be found [here](https://github.com/LupusInferni315/Stellarwolf.Core/blob/V1.0.0/ChaosEngine.cs).

Comment: Unfortunately no. I also have no clue what you're trying to ask. Do you want multiple threads to operate on the same data?

Comment: @PMF in a sense yes, the specific class I'm referring to is a random number generator, It doesn't allow direct access to it's internal state (which changes anytime a number is generated) and merely uses that state to return a value. I'm can't guarantee that each caller will be on the same thread, but I do need to be referring to the same state regardless of thread.

Comment: Can you provide code for your exact scenario? Multi-threading is by its nature very difficult and no one can provide you a concrete answer, other than locking all gets/sets for every bit of state in your class. That would ensure your state cannot get corrupted, but could also potentially deadlock and/or have very poor performance.

Comment: Then just use the same instance of the random number generator in all threads. You might need a lock though, otherwise you could get weird results (unless the class is in itself threadsafe). Be aware that even if all threads share the same generator, the result for each thread will not be predictable. So if your application depends on the fact, that a pseudo-random-number-generator replays the same sequence when it's started with the same initial value, this won't work in a parallel scenario.

Comment: @PMF that could be a problem, The entire purpose for writing my own generator instead of using the built in one, is for the purpose of saving and loading the internal state, because the application I'm building it for (which is a game) will save and load the state of the shared instance (to prevent things like save scumming) when a game is saved and loaded.

Comment: @DavidL I'm not sure which code is actually required, The entire class is some 700 lines, I will at the very least provide the code showing the static members, as well as the fields and properties

Comment: You would need to provide at least the code that you are concerned about that composes the public api. That would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks foe the snippet. Very helpful! You are creating a new ChaosEngine per thread. Is that your intention? What does Reseed do?

Comment: @DavidL That is not my intention, and in essence Reseed clears the old state and builds a new state from the ground up, without creating a new instance of the class itself, I did post a link to the full code

Comment: The intention is to create 1 ChaosEngine for all threads

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your linked code, the critical operations seem to be the instantiation of the `Shared` instance and the `Reseed(int? seed)` method.

By changing your `Shared` instance to no longer use `[ThreadStatic]` and instead  initializing inline, you will have thread-safe instantiation, and it will remain thread-safe. This also allows you to remove `m_Shared`.

```
public static ChaosEngine Shared = new ChaosEngine();
```

That said, your call to `Seed` is not thread-safe since it can update the m_Seed value. One option is to lock inside of `Reseed(int? seed)` which means any reads to `Seed` may not be thread-safe, but any writes to `m_Seed` would be synchronized.

```
private static readonly object s_seedLocker = new object();

public int? Seed { get => m_Seed; set => Reseed(value); }

public void Reseed(int? seed)
{
    lock (s_seedLocker)
    {
        m_Seed = seed ?? Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
        ...
    }
}
```

You'll have to determine if this is sufficient for your needs. If not, you'd need to synchronize all access to `Seed`.

```
private static readonly object s_seedLocker = new object();

public int? Seed
{
    get
    {
        lock (s_seedLocker)
        {
            return m_Seed;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        lock (s_seedLocker)
        {
            Reseed(value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that in the following scenario:

```
var seed1 = ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed;

var engine = new ChaosEngine();
var seed2 = engine.Seed;
    
var seed3 = ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed;
```

`seed1` and `seed3` will be identical, but `seed2` will be unique. It is unclear if this is behavior that you would expect.

You do have the ability to synchronize each instantiation of `ChaosEngine` to the same seed with the following:

```
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
Task.Run(() => new ChaosEngine(ChaosEngine.Shared.Seed.Value));
```

which will use the same common seed value for all instances.

Comment: that behavior is what is expected, seed1 and seed3 should be identical and seed2 should (or rather could) be different, the intention is to be able to create an instance that does not effect and is not effected by the shared instance

Comment: As for the access to the static state, would putting the lock in the `Shared` property be sufficient for making/keeping access thread-safe? I saw the lock around the Seed access, and from what I understand (which is admittedly not a lot when it comes to multi-threading) and have read, the locks are only necessary when initially accessing, which would all be behind `Shared`, unless I'm missing something else.

Comment: It isn’t entirely clear why Seed has to be public in the first place, or when you would update seed on the Shared instance or any other. What type of access to Shared needs to be protected against synchronized access other than Seed?

Comment: All of the methods that generate a value, also modify the internal state of the generator. Every method if you trace it back leads to the private method `NextSample()` which on calling changes a value in the seed array, which is the main part that needs to be synchronized across threads.

Comment: What do you mean it needs to be synchronized across threads? Per instance of ChaosEngine, or across all instances of ChaosEngine?

Comment: When creating an instance of ChaosEngine it populates the SeedArray, everytime you generate a new value it modifies the array, if two threads are calling the Shared instance of the engine, the modified array should be used when generating the second value, as for `Seed` being public, and subsequently being able to change the seed, that is not strictly necessary just figured it would be a convenient option as opposed to creating a new instance every time you wanted to change the seed.

Comment: I'll have to re-review your implementation, but it sounds like essentially every public method has the ability to mutate state and will need synchronization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247044/discussion-between-rwolfe-and-david-l).